# spring-data-mongodb customRepository can't use dependency injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I was trying use `customRepository` to use Criteria in Repository. 
I create `customRepositoryImpl` and run success.
But I found that ,the property I added `@Autowire` annotation can't be injected automatically. 
Here is my code:

```
public class LogMessageRepositoryImpl implements LogMessageRepositoryCustom{
    @Resource
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public List<LogMessage> findByCriteria(){

        return mongoTemplate.find(query(where("level").regex("Info")),LogMessage.class);
    }
 }
```

`mongoTemplate` always be `null`;

I tried to debug it ,and find this bean definition's `dependsOn` is null.

can't figure out why?

Comment: Are you sure you have an instance of `MongoTemplate` in your `ApplicationContext`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use `@Autowired` instead of `@Resource`
2. Are you sure that bean is called "mongoTemplate" in your spring xml-config file? Could you provide a slice of your coniguration file related to mongo?

Comment: yes, I'm sure. 
Both `@Autowired` and `@Resource` were Tried.
I use this
      `@Resource`
       private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
in a normal bean ,that worked ,like controller.But don't this bean.

@Ali Dehghani